# ORA-01843: not a valid month even my date format is right

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to insert some data to my table but it keep showing ORA-01843: not a valid month even my month format is right.

This is my table structure :

```
create table PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN 
(
   ID_CHECK_IN          NUMBER               not null,
   NO_KTP               NUMBER(16)           not null,
   ID_KARYAWAN          NUMBER               not null,
   TANGGAL_CHECK_IN     DATE constraint nn_tgl_checkin not null,
   JAM_CHECK_IN         VARCHAR2(5) constraint uc_jamcheckin unique,   
   LAMA_MENGINAP        VARCHAR2(7)          not null,
   constraint PK_PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN primary key (ID_CHECK_IN)
);
```

and this is my insert query :

```
insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555551, 220180521, 8888881, to_date('20-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '17.21', '3 hari');
insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555552, 220180522, 8888882, to_date('21-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '19.18', '4 hari');
insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555553, 220180523, 8888883, to_date('22-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '20.55', '3 hari');
insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555554, 220180524, 8888884, to_date('23-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '13.21', '2 hari');
insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555555, 220180525, 8888885, to_date('24-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '19.38', '5 hari');
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my insert ?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d30e27403f1bd7c54155d962d9db09d

Comment: Date literals in Oracle are written like `date '2020-03-20'`. Using this standard avoids date language issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database doesn't speak English. So, make it:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555551, 220180521, 8888881, to_date('20-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), '17.21', '3 hari');

1 row created.
```

---

Alternatively, modify `TO_DATE` function call:

```
SQL> insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (5555551, 220180521, 8888881, to_date('20-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'nls_date_language = english'), '17.21', '3 hari');

1 row created.
```

Comment: Littlefoot, How did you know this error was coming due to language?

Comment: It was pretty much obvious, @Ankit; the only piece of code that references DATE value was the one that looked like "20-Mar-2020". As format mask was correct (DD-Mon-YYYY), it must have been the language. If the OP picked different format (numerics only, e.g. 20-03-2020), they would avoid such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your database/session set up as:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Indonesia';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'MALAY';
```

*(Or whichever non-English territory/language you have it set up as.)*

Then your query does not work as it does not know the month `Mar`. You could change the session settings; however, this is not a robust solution as you then need to remember to change the session every time you want to run a similar query.

A better solution is to add a 3rd argument to `TO_DATE` to specify the language:

```sql
insert into PENCATATAN_CHECK_IN values (
  5555551,
  220180521,
  8888881,
  to_date('20-Mar-2020', 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
  '17.21',
  '3 hari'
);
```

Then your query will work regardless of what language your database/session is expecting as you've told it what language you are using in the query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4accc673fa2600c58e160e9bd3c22b24)*